# How to pass props to styled component without converting them to transient props?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have created a `Text` component which receives couple of props. These props are passed to the styled component, where styles are applied. I dont want to pass props to the DOM, I only want to access them inside styled component.

Converting props to transient props works, but it creates repeating code which I think makes the whole component unnecessarily bigger.

I would like to know, how to pass some props to my styled component without passing them to the DOM and without having to redefine every prop. I tried using `shouldForwardProps` but I cant get it to work with Typescript.

```js
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  size: number;
  height: number;
  color: string;
};

const StyledText = styled.p<{ $color: string; $size: number; $height: number }>`
  color: ${({ $color }) => $color};
  font-size: ${({ $size }) => `${$size}px;`};
  line-height: ${({ $height }) => `${$height}px;`};
  ...
`;

const Text: React.FC<Props & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>> = ({ children, size, height, color, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <StyledText $size={size} $height={height} $color={color} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </StyledText>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `shouldForwardProps` as you suggested which I believe is what you are asking for. I've tried to tie in the `customAttributeNames` to the `Props`, but I've given up on that.

```
const customAttributeNames = ["size", "height", "color"] as const;

type TCustomAttribute = typeof customAttributeNames[number];

type Props = React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement> & {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  size: number;
  height: number;
  color: string;
};

const StyledTextWithoutDomAttributes = styled.p.withConfig({
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) =>
    !(customAttributeNames as readonly string[]).includes(prop)
})<Pick<Props, TCustomAttribute>>`
  color: ${({ color }) => color};
  font-size: ${({ size }) => `${size}px;`};
  line-height: ${({ height }) => `${height}px;`};
`;

const StyledTextWithDomAttributes = styled.p<Pick<Props, TCustomAttribute>>`
  color: ${({ color }) => color};
  font-size: ${({ size }) => `${size}px;`};
  line-height: ${({ height }) => `${height}px;`};
`;

const Text: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, size, height, color, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <StyledTextWithDomAttributes
        size={size}
        height={height}
        color={color}
        {...rest}
      >
        {children}
      </StyledTextWithDomAttributes>
      <StyledTextWithoutDomAttributes
        size={size}
        height={height}
        color={color}
        {...rest}
      >
        {children}
      </StyledTextWithoutDomAttributes>
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-leakey-o66bej?file=/src/App.tsx) so you can see it working.

Answer (score 0):

What you should thrive for is having a default StyledText component and then override this component using the `styled` function

```js
const StyledTextPrimary = styled.p`
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 130%;
`;
```

and then you override it like this

```js
const StyledTextLarge = styled(StyledText)`
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 140%;
`;
```

Usually in a design system, you define the different variants of your text/typography. It is limited (ie: heading, subheading, text). Therefore it is better to have different components like this than influencing the final user to pass variables that risk not to comply with the design you imagined

If you need to maintain a multitude of text component, you coud create then 1 component that takes an attribute « variant » and return the correct component based on a switch case or a hash table

here is a full example in typescript

```js
export enum ETextVariants {
  primary,
  large,
}

const variants = {
  [ETextVariants.primary]: StyledTextPrimary,
  [ETextVariants.large]: StyledTextLarge,
};

export interface ITextProps extends ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'p'> {
  variant?: ETextVariants;
}
export function StyledText({
  variant = ETextVariants.primary,
  children,
  ...props
}: ITextProps) {
  const TextComponent = variants[variant];
  return (
    <TextComponent {...props}>
      {children}
    </TextComponent>
  );
}
```

and you use it like this

```
  <StyledText>my text</StyledText>
  // or
  <StyledText variant={ETextVariants.large}>my text</StyledText>
```

you could also use strings instead of enums for the value of the variant, but it is common practice in development to use enums to save build space and memory

Here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/variants-on-a-styled-components-1pcjii

Comment: thank you for the comment. i have text and heading styles and i think it would be even harder to maintain 5-10 text components.

Comment: what's your use case exactly? I updated my answer to manage more components in the same place. The idea is to guide other developers or your future self toward using the same set of components. The "variant" variable helps you restrict the possibilities. I named this variable "variant" because in Figma designers use the same term